# Spring how to create POST request with empty body?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create a shopping Cart using Spring which will have `cartId, product name, price`. This will be done using a specific endpoint `/api/carts`. For this I would use the POST method and the `@RequestBody` but the requirement of my homework is to create a POST method with empty body. What is the logic around that?
How do I do that in Spring?

My understanding is that I am also supposed to send data in the body like `cartId, product name, price`. What am I missing?

My code would be something like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/api")
public class Controller {

  @Autowired
  CartService service;

  @PostMapping("/carts")
  ResponseEntity<CartDTO> createCart (@RequestBody CartDTO dto){
  Cart cart = new Cart(dto);
  etc
```

but the above will not have an empty body.
Can someone explain the difference in post method with empty body and with a body?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically impossible to post an empty body(aka no body)! You will always have a valid body for all requests based on http(see https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-5)! The task, written in this terminology, is nonsense.

But you can post a valid body size of 0 bytes. That is the most matching interpretation of an "empty body". You can signalize a empty body if you neither post a Content-Length nor a Transfer-Encoding header. But thats not a non-body term. You always send a body, even if its 0 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive it like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/carts")
        public ResponseEntity createCart(@RequestBody CartDTO dto) {

.....logic
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    
        }
```

This will only send the httpSTatus in response.